# Is my strategy to show a statement of the form $(x\in A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow(\exists y\in C\cap D)$ correct?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be arbitrary sets. Further, let $x$ be some well-defined object. I have a theorem of the following form:

*There exists an object $y$ in the intersection of sets $C$ and $D$ if and only if the object $x$ belongs to the intersection of sets $A$ and $B$. Formally,*
\begin{gather}
(x\in A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow(\exists y\in C\cap D)
\end{gather}

I also have an attempt of a proof that follows this simple two-fold structure:

1. I first show that if there exists some $y\in C$, then $x\in A\cap B$;
2. I then show that if $x\in A\cap B$, then there exists $y\in C\cap D$.

The only reason why I'm not sure whether my proof strategy works is because, in (1), I do not need the intersection of $C$ and $D$ to be non-empty for my object $x$ to belong to $A$ and $B$ (in fact, it suffices that $C$ is non-empty).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Logically, your approach is correct. However, you are saying that if $C$ is nonempty and, say, $D$ is empty or $D$ has empty intersection with $C$, then it already follows that $x\in A\cap B$ whereas obviously there won't be any $y\in C\cap D$. Thus, either (1) Your proof of the equivalence in the left-to-right direction is wrong, or alternatively (2) $C$ nonempty implies $x\in A\cap B$, which implies $C\cap D$ nonempty, i.e. it seems that $C$ nonempty implies $C\cap D$ is nonempty! Without knowing what those statements actually *mean* I cannot say anything more.

Comment: Expanding on Stinking Bishop (what a name :p), your purported proof actually shows that $(x\in A\cap B)\iff (\exists y \in C)$ (since of course $C\cap D$ non-empty implies $C$ non-empty). Which makes it seem like your actual proof is probably wrong... To say more, we would need to see some concrete details probably.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I can't provide any more details on the proof itself because that would require introducing a lot of field-specific notation and concepts. I see why my approach is probably wrong, but when checking the proof itself, I don't see what fails. I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: Side note: while $∃y{\in}\mathbb R\;P(y)$ is notational shorthand for $∃y\;\big(y\in\mathbb R\:\land\:P(y)\big),\,$ the isolated strings $\;∃y{\in}\mathbb R\;$ and $\;∀x{\in}\mathbb C\;$ are syntactically incorrect and do not mean “some $y$ is real” and “every $x$ is complex”. So, correction: $$x\in A\cap B\iff \exists y\;\; \color{red}y\in C\cap D.$$